# Generate binary matrix with millions of rows

Tags: python, matrix, scipy, sparse-matrix, complexity-theory

I am trying to generate a binary matrix using dok_matrix from scipy.sparse and a nested for loop, but the time complexity is too high (there are more than 23,6 million rows and 34565 columns).

Rows, articles['article_id] and articles['title'] in the code below contains strings. If the strings in the two subsequent variables contains a given string in rows, I want to add 1 to the binary matrix, otherwise -1.

There must be a faster way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix
data = dok_matrix((len(rows),articles['article_id'].size), dtype=np.int8)

for i in range(len(rows)):
    for j in range(articles['article_id'].size):
        if (rows[i] in articles['Content'][j]) or (rows[i] in articles['Title'][j]):
            data[i,j] = 1
        else:
            data[i,j] = -1
```

Comment: This does not look sparse. Each entry will be nonzero. Think about that before tackling fast loopless construction.

Comment: the -1 elements should actually be 0, but when I print the matrix, the console only outputs non zero elements